# Genymotion and oracle virtualbox

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have read some posts regarding how to solve problem with genymotion being unable to start any virtual device however my problem is that I couldnt open oracle vm virtualbox. when i double click on the icon nothing happens.

any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

just updated it to the latest version of oracle vm. solved the problem.